# Receive message from an Elm process

Tags: process, ipc, elm

I'm toying around with Elm [processes](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Process) in order to learn more about how they work. In parts of this, I'm trying to implement a timer.

I bumped into an obstacle, however: I can't find a way to access the result of a process' task in the rest of the code.

For a second, I hoped that if I make the task resolve with a `Cmd`, the Elm runtime would be kind enough to perform that effect for me, but that was a naive idea:

```elm
type Msg
  = Spawned Process.Id
  | TimeIsUp

init _ =
  ( Nothing
  , Task.perform Spawned (Process.spawn backgroundTask)
  )

backgroundTask : Task.Task y (Platform.Cmd.Cmd Msg)
backgroundTask =
  Process.sleep 1000
    -- pathetic attempt to send a Msg starts here
    |> Task.map ( always
                  <| Task.perform (always TimeIsUp)
                  <| Task.succeed ()
                )
    -- and ends here
    |> Task.map (Debug.log "Timer finished") -- logs "Timer finished: <internals>"

update msg state =
  case msg of
    Spawned id ->
      (Just id, Cmd.none)

    TimeIsUp ->
      (Nothing, Cmd.none)

view state =
  case state of
    Just id ->
      text "Running"

    Nothing ->
      text "Time is up"
```

The [docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Process) say

> there is no public API for processes to communicate with each other.

I'm not sure if that implies that a process can't cummunicate with the rest of the app.

Is there any way to have `update` function receive a `TimeIsUp` once the process exits?

Answer (score 1):

There is one way but it requires a port of hell:

1. make a fake HTTP request from the process,
2. then intercept it via JavaScript
3. and pass it back to Elm.

```elm
port ofHell : (() -> msg) -> Sub msg

subscriptions _ =
  ofHell (always TimeIsUp)

backgroundTask : Task.Task y (Http.Response String)
backgroundTask =
  Process.sleep 1000
    -- nasty hack starts here 
    |> Task.andThen ( always
                      <| Http.task { method = "EVIL"
                                   , headers = []
                                   , url = ""
                                   , body = Http.emptyBody
                                   , resolver = Http.stringResolver (always Ok "")
                                   , timeout = Nothing 
                                   }
                    )
```

Under the hood, `Http.task` invokes `new XMLHttpRequest()`, so we can intercept it by redefining that constructor.

```html
<script src="elm-app.js"></script>
<div id=hack></div>
<script>
  var app = Elm.Hack.init({
    node: document.getElementById('hack')
  })

  var orig = window.XMLHttpRequest
  window.XMLHttpRequest = function () {
    var req = new orig()
    var orig = req.open
    req.open = function (method) {
      if (method == 'EVIL') {
        app.ports.ofHell.send(null)
      }
      return orig.open.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    return req
  }
</script>
```

The solution is not production ready, but it does let you continue playing around with Elm processes.

Answer (score 1):

Elm Processes aren't a fully fledged API at the moment. It's not possible to do what you want with the `Process` library on its own.

See the notes in the docs for [Process.spawn](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Process#spawn):

> Note: This creates a relatively restricted kind of Process because it cannot receive any messages. More flexibility for user-defined processes will come in a later release!

and the whole [Future Plans](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Process#future-plans) section, eg.:

> Right now, this library is pretty sparse. For example, there is no public API for processes to communicate with each other.

Comment: So, (a) `Process` can't receive messages and (b) one `Process` can't talk to another `Process`. But does it imply that a spawned `Process` can't send messages to the "main app". Maybe it does, but I don't see how

Comment: I don't think there's a way given the current API.